# How to increment the number of payments with Stripe and PHP (for a subscription)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set a subscription and count the number of payments (with webhook).
I'm using this documentation :
https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/installment-plan#signing-up-a-customer-for-an-installment-plan

But it's Ruby on Rails.
I tried to add a metadata to count the payments :

```
       $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "items" => array(
      array(
          "plan" => $plan->id,
      ),
  ),   
   "metadata" => ["number_payments" => 0]));
```

Then in my webhook page, i'd like to retrieve subscription and increment the number of payments, but i don't understand and know how to do it with PHP (from the Stripe example code here) :

```
def increment_payments_count(event)
# Grab the subscription line item.
sub =  event.data.object.lines.data[0]

# Execute only for installment plans.
if !sub.metadata[:installments_paid].nil?
# Recommendation: Log invoices and check for duplicate events.
# Recommendation: Note that we send $0 invoices for trials.
#                 You can verify the `amount_paid` attribute of
#                 the invoice object before incrementing the count.

    # Retrieve and increment the number of payments.
    count = sub.metadata[:installments_paid].to_i
    count += 1
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the 'Update Subscription API' to update the metadata here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=ruby#update_subscription-metadata